# Extract new image dimensions from timthumb

Tags: php, image, resize, dimensions, timthumb

I'm using timthumb to resize my images because it scales them nicely if I only enter one of the dimensions.  However I want to know if it's possible to extract the new resized image's dimensions so that I can add that dynamically to the img tag attributes.

I tried this with no luck:

```
$fullpath = '/lib/timthumb.php?src='.$image.'&w=100';
$my_image = array_values(getimagesize($fullpath));
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = $my_image;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not sure how to read the thumb generated in the cache by timthumb directly, this should work:

```
$fullpath = '/lib/timthumb.php?src='.$image.'&w=' . $newWidth;

#array with 0 being the width, and 1 being the height, and some other values as well
$oldDims = getimagesize($image);

#timthumb uses floor(), so mimicing here
$newHeight = floor($newWidth / $oldDims[0] * $oldDims[1]);
```

Comment: I'm testing this out and so far it seems to be doing exactly as I need.  Will follow up and let you know after further testing.  Thanks!

Comment: It should work, since it's basically the exact same calculation timthumb is doing ;)

Answer (score -1):

My idea would be to scale the images before they are uploaded to the server. If you have a lot of images resizing them this way is an expensive operation. Also you don't need timthumb php can do this on it's own. So if you really *need* to resize images on the server try something like...

```
$size = gewtimagesize($image);
$dimensions = $size['3'];//returns height="xxx" width="xxx"
$img = <<<IMG
    <img src="path/to/img" $dimensions >
IMG;
echo $img;
```

I don't know if it works, but it looks right to me

--EDIT--
Nevermind this won't work for you

Comment: He's using timthumb for that right? I was answering his question " However I want to know if it's possible to extract the new resized image's dimensions so that I can add that dynamically to the img tag attributes."

Comment: `$image` is the old, original image.  The issue is that timthumb dynamically generates an image in cache, so he can't use `getimagesize()` as he doesn't have the file path to the new image . . .